# Problem with resizeObserver, React and probably re-render issue (not yet identified)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observers, resize-observer

I've got a problem in my application. I've made a component that wrap a `children` and display a "Show more/less" around it. It accepts an `initialHeight` and a `MaxHeight` which are 2 numbers, that I print in inline style. I then compare the children height and the `initialHeight` because if the children is smaller than I allow, there is no need to display the Show More things.

My problem is that I'm trying to handle a specific case : in one case the children is a component that contains an API call and display a loader by default. When API call is successful, I receive images and I hide the loader. Which means for the first seconds my children height is around 80px (loader) then it can be something like 600px or more (images).
So I used an `observer`, thinking it was the best solution :

```js
import {useState, useRef, useEffect, MutableRefObject} from 'react'
import {IoIosArrowUp, IoIosArrowDown} from 'react-icons/io'
import styles from './ShowMoreWrapper.module.scss'

type PropsTypes = {
  children: React.ReactNode
  initialHeight: number
  maxHeight: number
}

const ShowMoreWrapper = ({
  children,
  initialHeight,
  maxHeight,
}: PropsTypes): JSX.Element => {
  const [innerExpand, setInnerExpand] = useState(false)
  const [showActions, setShowActions] = useState(false)
  const childrenRef = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>
  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    if (entries[0].target.clientHeight > initialHeight) {
      setShowActions(true)
      setInnerExpand(false)
    }
    observer.unobserve
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.observe(childrenRef.current)
  }, [childrenRef])

  const toggleExpand = () => {
    setInnerExpand(!innerExpand)
    if (wrapperRef.current && wrapperRef.current.scrollTop > 0) {
      wrapperRef.current.scrollTop = 0
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={wrapperRef}
        className={styles.contentWrapper}
        data-inner-expand={innerExpand}
        style={{
          maxHeight: innerExpand ? `${maxHeight}px` : `${initialHeight}px`,
        }}
      >
        <div ref={childrenRef}>{children}</div>
      </div>
      {showActions && (
        <div
          className={styles.innerExpandActions}
          onClick={toggleExpand}
          data-inner-expand={innerExpand}
        >
          <span>Show {innerExpand ? 'less' : 'more'}</span>
          {innerExpand ? <IoIosArrowUp /> : <IoIosArrowDown />}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default ShowMoreWrapper
```

I then have some CSS to handle scollbar and overflow :

```css
.contentWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;

  &[data-inner-expand='true'] {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

My problem is when I click on the `Show more` button, it tries to set `innerExpand` to `!innerExpand` to toggle but immediately it reset itself to false, probably because `observer` is re-defined on re-render maybe ?

Comment: You should declare your observer in a `useEffect` instead of directly in the render function like you do now. And don't forget to call `observer.disconnect()` in the [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).